# How to load and use modules in embedded JavaScript (EJS) code

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, geotiff, embedded-javascript

My current scripts/codes flow is `index.js->routes.js->main.ejs` I need to load a GeoTiff-related module and use its plotting functions in my `main.ejs`. However I find that `ejs` does not support loading modules within the code, so I need to load the GeoTiff modules in my `index.js` or `routes.js` and render the functions to `main.ejs`.
I found some examples from Google and followed their methods but unfortunately I couldn't make it work. The error information keeps showing that the `GeoTiff-related functions in main.ejs are not defined`.

The github website of the module I try to use is here:

- https://github.com/geotiff/georaster-layer-for-leaflet

As you can see in the Usage Example it directly `require` the georaster and then compose the plot functions in the same js code, whereas in my case my plot codes will be in my `main.ejs` where **I can not `require` the georaster directly.**

Following the method in this page:
https://rajuthapa-13222.medium.com/how-to-use-node-packages-on-ejs-html-templating-engine-d51885e91deb
I tried the following codes in my `routes.js`

```
var parse_georaster = require("georaster");
var GeoRasterLayer = require("georaster-layer-for-leaflet");

var getMain = function (req, res) {
   res.render('main',{parse_georaster: parse_georaster,GeoRasterLayer: GeoRasterLayer});
};
```

But it seems not working. I still can not use the function of `parse_georaster` and `GeoRasterLayer` in my `main.ejs`.